# How to Insert new data in existing array in Firebase Database from Android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm Learning the Firebase Database with Android, Having array of data in Firebase Database Like Below image.

[image]

**cineIndustry** is an Array of data. In **JSON** it looks Like this

```
 "cineIndustry" : [ {
   "type" : "Hollywood"
 }, {
   "type" : "Kollywood"
 }, {
   "type" : "Bollywood"
 } ]
```

I want Insert new data in this Array.

**POJO Class**

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
public class CineIndustry {

void CineIndustry(){}

public String type;

}
```

**Save new data**

```
CineIndustry cineIndustry = new CineIndustry();
cineIndustry.type = cineType.getText().toString();

mDatabase.setValue(cineIndustry);
```

When i insert like above it will replace Array. JSON Structure was change to normal **JSON object** instated of **JSON Array**.

Anyone know help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is happening because you are `overwriting` the data. You are using the `setValue()` method, instead of using `updateChildren()` method.

Please do the following changes and your problem will be solved.

So, in order to write data objects to your Firebase database, instead of using an `Array` or a `List`, I suggest you using a `Map`. To save data, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference cineIndustryRef = rootRef.child("cineIndustry").push();
String key = cineIndustryRef.getKey();
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(key, "Hollywood");
//and os on
cineIndustryRef.updateChildren(map);
```

As you can see, I have called `updateChildren()` method directly on the reference. In the end, the database should look like this:

```
Firebase-root
    |
    ---- cineIndustry
            |
            ---- pushedId1: "Hollywood"
            |
            ---- pushedId2: "Kollywood"
            |
            ---- pushedId2: "Bollywood"
```

Comment: Can't insert the data i expect right. Insert data only like you suggest.

Comment: your answer is working fine. your structure is different and My structure is different. So, not possible create structure like `"cineIndustry" : [ {
   "type" : "Hollywood"
 }, {
   "type" : "Kollywood"
 }, {
   "type" : "Bollywood"
 } ]` this. Your answer is the only way right.

Comment: This is a proposal for changing the database. No, you cannot have different childrens with the same key, because in the case of a `Map`, it replaces the old value with the new one. So that why you need different keys.

Comment: Okay I'll go with your answer.