# Read Data from Firebase to Android no code currently

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am a beginner using Android Studio and Firebase and I am struggling with reading data from my Firebase Database and displaying it in activity in Android.

This is my database currently (Please Correct me if I am wrong);

[image]

I want the companies to display in an activity with their logo and company name - in a list view.

I then want to be able to add multiple reviews for that company which displays when the company is selected.

Reviews are entered using spinners which are stored in another activity.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I've tried many resources online and can't figure this out.

Comment: summarising your question, it looks like you want to perform read, write operation into firebase db. both this operation quite simple, plz read the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write                                       
Read: attach a value listener to the branch where you want to observe change, you will get the data in ondatachange,                                                                                    Write: Refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44694685/7735032

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you do the database something like this.

```
DatabaseReference mDB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

Company mCompany = new Company(name,logo);
mDB.child("Company").push().setValue(mCompany);
```

You can refer to this link to make the listview
https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md